# windows communication foundation 4 ssl issue

Tags: wcf, ssl

I am facing a strange issue with wcf on ssl.
I have a silverlight application using wcf service on ssl. The service call fails for the first time its called. It gives the generic not found issue. I have a trace running on the service and it does not record any hits. However if i catch the error, recreate the proxy and call the method it works fine. If i run the  service on http i do not run into this issue.
The wcf service is hosted in IIS7. fiddler does show call being made to the service but the tracelog does not record any incoming calls.
any help is much appreciated

thanks
Ben